# Authenticate with API using OpenID connect from a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, openid-connect

I've got a cloud migration coming up and we previously did a lot of work transferring data between on-prem databases. The cloud provider is building API's for us to interface with the db once it's in the cloud, so I'm trying to write a Windows Service that will periodically suck some data out of our other on-prem db and post it to the cloud db. I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement OpenID Connect authentication in c# in a windows service. All the examples I've seen are web applications. Has anyone tried this?

If anyone has a better idea than a windows service, I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should look for is the **client credentials flow** (part of OpenID Connect). It is the flow you use when you have no user involved when requesting tokens.

To get a token, you can use the IdentityModel helper library and you can find sample code [here](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html#requesting-a-token-using-the-client-credentials-grant-type):

If you don't want to use a windows service, then the alternative is to create a console application that you schedule to be called using the windows built in task scheduler.
Alternatively, take a look at [HangFire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll do more research on those but this sounds like exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as an acceptable answer if you like it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my service talking with the API. The basic flow is that you request a Bearer token, then pass the token in corresponding requests. Here's an example of the function I'm using to request tokens:

```
public static async Task<string> RequestTokenAsync()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string token;
        var con = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "XXXXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "XXXXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", "XXXXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "XXXXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("device_id", "XXXXX"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("company", "XXXXX")
        };

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://whatever/connect/token"),
            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(con)
            {
                Headers =
                {
                    ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                }
            }
        };
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                token = body;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "ERROR: " + ex.Message;
        }

        Dictionary<string, object> values =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(token);
        values.TryGetValue("access_token", out object extractedToken);

        return extractedToken.ToString();
    }
```

And here's an example of using the token:

```
public static async Task<List<Location>> GetLocations()
    {
        List<Location> result = new List<Location>();

        string jsonResponse;
        var client = new HttpClient();
        string token = await RequestTokenAsync();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://whatever/v1/Locations"),
        };
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                jsonResponse = body.ToString();
                try
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Location>>(jsonResponse);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

        return result;
    }
```